# If $B_n\subset[0,1]$ are Borel and $\exists b > 0$ s.t. the Lebesgue measure of each $B_n$ is $>b$, show that there's a point in infinitely many $B$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $B_n$ be a countable collection of Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$ . Suppose that there is $b > 0$ such that the Lebesgue measure of each $B_n$ is greater than $b$. Show that there is at least one point which belongs to infinitely many $B$.

Comment: This is from John Walsh's book,no??

Comment: yes. do you know how i can get the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I will prove the contrapositive assertion, that if no point belongs to infinitely many of the sets $B_n,$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)=0.$

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $A_n=B_n\setminus\bigcup_{m=n+1}^\infty B_m.$ The sets $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint. Because of our assumption that no point belongs to infinitely many $B_n,$ we have $B_n\subseteq\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m.$

Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\lt\infty,$$
it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(B_n)\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=n}^\infty\mu(A_m)=0.$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: I am not sure how you get the equality $B_n=\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m$. The $\subset$ direction indeed follows from our assumption but the other direction does not.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for your swift reaction (I have already upvoted).